# What's the wavelength of an electron after hitting a potential barrier?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-electrodynamics, wavelength

I have this question:

> An electron with Energy $E = 40 eV$ hits a potential barrier with $E_0 = 30 eV$. What is the wavelength of the electron after hitting the potential barrier?

I worked from the energy $E = p\cdot v \Rightarrow m_e \cdot E = p^2$ and combined it with the DeBroglie Wavelength $\lambda \cdot p = h$ which yields

$$
  \lambda = \frac{h}{\sqrt{m_e \cdot (E-E_0)}}
$$

However, the sample solution says the wave number is

$$
  k = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda} = \frac{\sqrt{2\cdot m_e \cdot (E-E_0)}}{\hbar}
$$

Which is exactly what I got, except for the $2$ inside the root.

**Where does that factor come from? Why is my lacking of it wrong?**

---

*Note: I tagged this homework although it's not really homework, but homework-like head-scratching.*

Comment: Not to worry, the [tag:homework] tag is entirely appropriate here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint to the question(v1): The electron travels at non-relativistic speed. What is the non-relativistic formula for [kinetic energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy) of a point particle?

Comment: D'oh, silly me. I always neglect those pesky constants.